# django catch exception in view and redirect

Tags: python, django, exception, view

I have a view which is calling another function:

```
def someview(request):
    myfunc(**kwargs):
    #catch exception from myfunc
    if exception ValidationError:
         return render("sometemplate.html)
    elif exception IntegrityError:
        return render("sometemplate1.html")
    else:
        return render("sometemplate2.html")
```

Here myfunc is return some exception. If there is exceptions in that function I want to redirect my view. 
How can I catch exception and redirect the view.
Thank you

Comment: `try/except` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `try/except`

```
def someview(request):
    try:
        myfunc(**kwargs):
    except ValidationError:
        return render("sometemplate.html")
    except IntegrityError:
        return render("sometemplate1.html")

    return render("success.html")
```

Comment: Moving the return value outside of the `try` clause would be better, since otherwise you will also catch the exceptions for rendering the template

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know I had to finish the try/except before rendering template. It's weird : render, redirect... can be triggered in `except` but not in `try`